# MySql 5.7 Timestamp works in windows but not on linux

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table using the script down below and getting the error
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'LAST_MODIFIED_TS.

In my understanding after 5.6 you could create more than one timestamp column also it is not necessary to provide default values . Another thing is it is not barfing at Created_TS which is just one line before it.

Also the same script works on windows but not on linux ubuntu , the version of mysql running on both of them is 5.7

```
CREATE TABLE testdb.test (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    CREATED_TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    LAST_MODIFIED_TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PROPERTY_TYPE VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'S',
    last_modified timestamp  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY
        (ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Comment: This works on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88c649.

Comment: As i said myself it works on Windows box but not on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have **NO_ZERO_DATE** **sql_mode** variable set (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) by running the following query:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode';
```